# Renaming Factors in an ANOVA Table

Tags: r, anova, kable

I would like to rename the outputs of my two-way ANOVA table. Here is the code for the table:

````
```{r complete model anova weld}
weld$fgage = as.factor(weld$gage); weld$ftime = as.factor(weld$time)
wmoda = aov(weld$strength ~ weld$fgage*weld$ftime); waova = anova(wmoda) 
waova2 = round(waova, 2)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '-')
kable(waova2, col.names = c("Df", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F-Value", "P- 
Value"),
caption = '\\label{tab:waova}The two-way ANOVA table for the welding 
experiment (complete model).')
```
````

Here is what the table looks like when it is printed:
[image: ANOVA table]

I would like to change the names in the left-most column (weld$fgage, weld$ftime, and weld*fgage* : weld*ftime*), because they prevent the table from being more presentable.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example, you could use the following code before

````
```{r complete model anova weld}
weld$fgage = as.factor(weld$gage); weld$ftime = as.factor(weld$time)
wmoda = aov(weld$strength ~ weld$fgage*weld$ftime); waova = anova(wmoda) 
waova2 = round(waova, 2)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '-')
row.names(waova2)[1:3] = c("Factor A", "Factor B", "Interaction")
kable(waova2, col.names = c("Df", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F-Value", "P- 
Value"),
caption = '\\label{tab:waova}The two-way ANOVA table for the welding 
experiment (complete model).')
```
````